# Making a UITabBarController and UINavigationController Programmatically Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

I am trying to make a `UITabBarController` and a `UINavigationController` programmatically. I've tried many tutorials but most use Swift 3 which is too outdated and doesn't work.

**AppDelegate.swift Snippet:**

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let journalVC = JournalTableViewController()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: journalVC)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

**JournalTableViewController.swift Snippet:**

```
var tabBarCnt = UITabBarController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabBarCnt = UITabBarController()
    tabBarCnt.tabBar.barStyle = .black

    let journalVC = JournalTableViewController()
    journalVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .favorites, tag: 0)

    tabBarCnt.viewControllers = [journalVC]
    self.view.addSubview(tabBarCnt.view)

}
```

**What works:**

- The build loads onto the simulator

**What doesn't work:**

- The build crashes once loading onto the simulator
- After crashing, the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee6c2ada8)` apears over this line `12` of **JournalTableViewController.swift Snippet**

Comment: inside the viewdidload of journal table view controller you are instantiating another journal table view controller, this goes forever. The way you approach to create tabbar is not correct.

Comment: If you want to use both a navigation controller and a tab bar, you would probably want the tab bar controller to be your root view controller.  In each tab you can create a separate `UINavigationController` with the relevant first view controller for each tab.  This way the user can switch between tabs and navigate a stack of view controllers in each tab

Comment: @Paulw11 that looks like it might work but do you think you could post that as an answer with some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is  a typo in your snippet. In the following code, we added an intermediate vc to solve recursive problems.

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let journalVC = JournalViewController()
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: journalVC)
window?.rootViewController = navController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true
}
```

Here is journal vc:

```
class JournalViewController: UIViewController{

var tabBarCnt = UITabBarController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabBarCnt = UITabBarController()
    tabBarCnt.tabBar.barStyle = .black

    let journalVC = JournalTableViewController()
    journalVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .favorites, tag: 0)

    tabBarCnt.viewControllers = [journalVC]
    self.view.addSubview(tabBarCnt.view)

  }

 }
```

while the tableviewcontroller should be like this:

```
class JournalTableViewController: UITableViewController{


 }
```

Comment: This doesn't add a UITabBarController - just the UINavigationController shows up

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer, `tabBarController` should be root  instead of navController, and this `rootViewController` would includes a navigationController for each of its tab item.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to combine a `UITabBarController` and a `UINavigationController` then you will want the tab bar controller to be the root view controller.  Each tab can have its own navigation controller if required.

If you make the navigation controller the root, then as soon as you push a new view controller, the tab bar will disappear.  By making the tab bar the root, you can have a series of navigation hierarchies and switch quickly between them using the tab buttons.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let journalVC = JournalViewController()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: journalVC)

    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    navController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .favorites, tag: 0)
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [navController]

    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

There is no need for any specific code in your view controller class.

**JournalTableViewController.swift Snippet:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: `navController`is not being used in the solution you provided, is that a mistake?

Comment: Why are you setting `tabBarItem` to `journalVC` instead of `navController`?